# Can not find module import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'; import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

Tags: angular, ionic3, karma-jasmine

Can not find module:

`import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';`

`import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';`

I am using ionic 3, wanted to do Unit testing on my application but facing problem in `spec.ts` file, which is unable to find modules.

I am using **Karma** and **jasmine** for unit testing

Comment: Can you share your karma conf?

Comment: I used this blog https://riptutorial.com/ionic2/example/29543/unit-tests-with-karma-jasmine

Comment: I'm still blind, because blog is one thing, how you used the knowledge is something different... Karma is not jest / enzyme it works absolutely different - imagine test you run is actually runned as <script> at the end of <body> to use imports, you have to include test files also in files (karma.conf) to let them be processed by preprocessors. You can also write `debugger;` at the beginning of your test to pause debugger in browser to check if you're in right context etc. If global imports do not work try local like: `./node_modules/ionic-angular`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may happen that in your `tsconfig.json`, you might have put "**/*.spec.ts" under "exclude". So, remove it from there and put it under "include".
Please check this link for reference.

[Cannot find module in .spec.ts file in Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150417/cannot-find-module-in-spec-ts-file-in-ionic-3)